# Weird ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

I am getting a weird array index out of bound exception when I use the length of the array as the index

I have twice checked everything and printed some stuff like the array.length to the console

Here is the problematic code

```java
public static boolean doJumpSearch(int array[], int number) {

           int start = 0;
           int end = (int) Math.sqrt(array.length); 



           while(array[end] <= number && end < array.length) {
              start = end; 
              end += (int)Math.sqrt(array.length);
              if(end > array.length - 1)
                 end = array.length; 
           }

           for(int i = start; i<end; i++) { 
              if(array[i] == number)
                 return true; 
           }
           return false;

    }
```

Here is the runner code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = {1, 2, 3};



        if(search.doJumpSearch(a, 3)) System.out.println("Yup");

    }
```

Here is the error

```css
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at Rector.array.search.doJumpSearch(search.java:46)
    at dummy.main(dummy.java:12)
```

Comment: Did you trace step by step the code? The error is thrown here: `if(array[i] == number)` because `i` is greater than 2.

Answer (score 3):

The statement marked by // 1 followed by the statement marked by // 2 will cause the exception:

```
       while(array[end] <= number && end < array.length) { // 2
          start = end; 
          end += (int)Math.sqrt(array.length);
          if(end > array.length - 1)
             end = array.length;  // 1
       }
```

You should probably change the loop's condition to:

```
while(end < array.length && array[end] <= number)
```

to take advantage of the short circuit behavior of `&&` (i.e. only evaluate `array[end]` if `end < array.length` is `true`).

Answer (score 1):

Array elements go from `0` to `array.length - 1`.  So `array[end]` will give an exception if `end >= array.length`.

In your method, this can happen in two scenarios:

- when you assign `array.length` to `end`
- when you calculate `end` to be `(int) Math.sqrt(array.length)`, and `array.length` is `1`.

Now you are checking that `end < array.length` in the `while` condition, but unfortunately you check *after* evaluating the subexpression that does the indexing.